# PHP - Unable to pass select value to other pages

Tags: php

I have two pages, one passing values to the other through POST.  The values do not show on the second page from the select actions.  Input textboxes pass their values. I have included both pages below

First Page:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Unable to connect");
    mysql_select_db("testsite");

$sql = "SELECT state FROM states";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$sqldegrees = "SELECT degree FROM degrees";
$resultdegrees = mysql_query($sqldegrees);

$sqlschools = "SELECT school FROM schools";
$resultschools = mysql_query($sqlschools);


echo "<html>";
echo "<head>";
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'/>";
echo "</head>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<h3>Education</h3>";
echo "<form method='post' action='educationhistoryinsert.php'>";
echo "<table border='3' width='280'>";
echo "<tr><td>State:</td><td>";
echo "<select state='state'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['state'] ."'>" . $row['state'] ."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>School:</td><td>";
echo "<select school='school'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultschools)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['school'] ."'>" . $row['school'] ."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Degree:</td><td>";
echo "<select degree='degrees'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultdegrees)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['degree'] ."'>" . $row['degree'] ."</option>";}
echo "</select>";
echo "</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>Subject:</td><td><input type='text' name='subject' maxlength='20'/></td>      
</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='5'>Month:</td><td><input  style='width: 30px;' type='number'     
name='month' maxlength='1'/></td>";
echo "<td width='5'>Year:</td><td><input  style='width: 50px;' type='number'      
name='year' maxlength='5'/></td>";
echo "<td width='5'>GPA:</td><td><input  style='width: 30px;' type='number' name='gpa'    
maxlength='5'/></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Save'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

=======-------------------------------
'educationhistoryinsert.php'

```
<?php
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];

echo $degree."<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: `echo "<select degree='degrees'>";` change it to `echo "<select name='degree'>";`

Comment: Why must ppl use php to generate HTML (rhetorical question). You also haven't defined your doctype therefore your page will use the browsers' quirks mode and display differently in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your select names -

```
echo "<select state='state'>";
echo "<select school='school'>";
echo "<select degree='degrees'>";
```

to

```
echo "<select name='state'>";
echo "<select name='school'>";
echo "<select name='degrees'>";
```

also

```
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
```

is missing the `s` in `degrees`

```
$degree = $_POST['degrees'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `name` to the select boxes like

```
echo "<select name='degree'>";
echo "<select name='school'>";
```

And then you can get them via `POST` like

```
$degree = $_POST['degree'];
$school = $_POST['school'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using HTML (not XML) so you need to provide default tag attributes such as `name=""`*** OR use** `data-XYZ`

where **XYZ** is your custom attribute.

So in order to get correct result just replace

- `state='state'` with `name='state'`
- `school='school'` with `name ='school'`
- `degree='degrees'` with `name ='degrees'`

then it should work